# Is it true chosson and kallah must separate after the first night together?

Tags: halacha, wedding, niddah

After the chuppah and the chasuna celibrations have ended. They are not only permitted to be together but is a mitzvah. However,is it true chosson and kallah must separate after the first night together?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: Before getting married women generally take a taharas hamishpacha class with a local kallah teacher. I would highly recommend men also taking a similar class with a trusted rabbi. This is exactly the kind of thing that your teacher will go over with you.

Comment: Just about to start chosson classes. Heard this from a friend. Will learn soon but didn't wanna be completely shocked by new information in the class

Answer (score 4):

Yes; See *Darke'i Taharah* (HaRav Mordekha'i Eliyahu ZY'A"A) Chapter 10 ("Dine'i Kallah"), Halakhah 26 (s.v. "Be'ilat Miẓwah") which states (my translation):

> הַבּוֹעֵל אֶת הַבְּתוּלָה - בּוֹעֵל "בְּעִילַת-מִצְוָה" וְגוֹמֵר בִּיאָתוֹ וּפוֹרֵשׁ מִיָּד, וְאַחַר-כָּךְ טְמֵאָה הָאִשָּׁה מִדַּם הַבְּתוּלִים כְּאִלּוּ הָיָה זֶה דַּם-נִדָּה. וּמִכֵּיוָן שֶׁאֵין זֶה דַּם-נִדָּה מַמָּשׁ, דִּינָיו שׁוֹנִים מְעָט
>
> He who consummates with a virgin, consummates the "consummation of a miẓwah" and finishes the act and separates [from his kallah] immediately. And thereafter the wife is ritually impure from *Dam Betulim* as if it were the type of blood which renders a woman *niddah*. And, because this is not exactly the type of blood which renders a woman *niddah*, its corresponding laws differ slightly [...]

Comment: Not everyone bleeds...

Comment: @Dude - True; but, HaRav Eliyahu states in Halakhah 28 (same section) that this applies even to a woman who checked herself and did not find blood (for fear that she did bleed even a drop and that that drop was lost in motion). See inside.

Comment: Your use of "e'i" in "Dine'i" and in "Be'ilat" seems inconsistent.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm open to suggestions. I'm trying to find an accurate way to transliterate the *ẓere'i*, which won't include the traditional transliteration of "ay". As for the apostrophe in "Be'ilat", that's to underscore the gutteral "'ayin".